# What's the code flow for Web API in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've been learning how to make WEB APIs with ASP.NET for several days but I could not find out how the whole process works generally from the very first beginning, a request from a browser, to the end, response sent to client.

I just want to see the code flow. What first starts to work when a request comes in and how it continues throughout the app?

Do you have any resources for that?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/lifecycle-of-Asp-Net-web-api-message/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET life cycle is well encapsulated here: https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf